# Degree function in iGraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the `degree` function in iGraph R and have the following results

```
G<-read.graph("sample.graphml", format="graphml") 
degree(G)            

> degree(G)
 [1]   2  18   6  15  64  64  11  36  53  63  54  54  47  72  86  46  55  17
[19]   9  14  13   6  14  17  14   8  16   8  20  13  14  17  13  17  13   2
```

The values are the degree calculated for each node, but it does not display the corresponding node id. I look through the description of the function but still do not find a parameter that output the node id as well.

```
dput(G)
structure(list(6, FALSE, c(1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5), c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 4), c(0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6), c(0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6), c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 7), c(0, 2, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
structure(list(id = c("6", "4", "2", "5", "1", "3")), .Names = "id"), 
list()), <environment>), class = "igraph")

> degree(G)            
[1] 2 3 2 2 2 3
```

Comment: With "node id" do you mean "name"? Because otherwise, the results are in order, i.e. the node with id 1 has a degree of 2, the node with id 2 has a degree of 18, and so on.

Comment: I am trying to print out the name because only in that way, I can see which node has the highest degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is the degree for each node using its node number as the ordering. There is not much of a reason to print out the numbers 1 to 36 if you just want the node number. But, if available,  `degree` will print out the node *name* as the names of the elements in the output. For example,

```
## Sample graph
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
G = erdos.renyi.game(8, 0.35)

## make sure that each node has a name
V(G)$name = LETTERS[1:8]

## Display degree
degree(G) 
A B C D E F G H 
1 2 2 4 5 1 2 3
```

**Addition in response to added example**

First, it appears that you are not using the current version of `igraph`. I would recommend updating to the current version. But as in my previous example, you can get what you are looking for by using the `name` attribute of the vertices. Using your example, the node names are not shown.

```
degree(G)
[1] 2 3 2 2 2 3
```

But if I transfer `id` over to `name`, the degree sequence is labeled with the names.

```
V(G)$name = V(G)$id
degree(G)
6 4 2 5 1 3 
2 3 2 2 2 3
```

The top row is the id/name. The bottom row is the degree.

Comment: I am not sure why it's not printing out the node name. My network data is an edge list so that each line indicates an edge.

Comment: Could you please do `dput(G)` and paste the result into the question so that I can see exactly what you are seeing?

Comment: The question has been updated. The output has too many lines so I paste the last few lines.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I cannot make a graph from that.  Can you make a smaller example so that you _can_ paste the full output into the question?

Comment: I have created a small "bridge" network data and updated the question with output from `dput(G)` as well as output from `degree(G)`

Comment: Thanks. I will add something to my answer.